# Load controller's view in iframe without layout items

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 separate solutions.  I want to load one of project#1's content from its view in an iframe in project#2.  The problem is inside the iframe, it also includes everything in its layout view (the header/footer,etc)

How can I load just the view? (while still using its controller) in the iframe?

Comment: +1, how to switch layout depend on if the page is in an IFrame?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the layouts then you have to return partial views from those controller actions.

Ex.

```
return PartialView("ViewName");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your _Layout view You can generate target link with your IFrame like:-

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", null, new {target ="MainiFrame"})</li>
```

and in your Content section (in _Layout view) like:-

```
<section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
                <iframe name="MainiFrame" src="" width="920" height="1000" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </section>
```

Then any view that you like to display in your IFrame you can write the following code in the upper corner of that view.

```
 @model YourProgramName.YourModelClass

    @{
        Layout = null;
        ViewBag.Title = "Your View Title";
    }

@* Rest of your codes and mark ups.......... *@
```

Telling that your view not to use the default Layout, other wise your view will load all of your _Layout elements like menus, banners etc.

Enjoy.